# What is the difference among expressions of "classify something as"

Tags: expressions, verbs, differences

What is the difference among expressions of "classify something as"

1. classify something as A or B
2. classify something as A and B
3. classify something as either A or B
4. classify something into A and B

Comment: I've never actually heard *classify something* ***into***, but I'd interpret it as the same as *classify as*, with the possible subtlety that the thing is being grouped with a bunch of other things that are also considered *A and B*. But, in general, this is no different than the the meanings of *or*, *and*, and *either or*.

Answer (score 1):

Classifying something as A or B means that something can be categorized as type A or type B but not both.

Classifying something as A and B means that something is both A and B. It can be categorized as having the characteristics of type A and type B.

Classifying something as either A or B is almost the same as the first example, A or B. There is an additional possible nuance, which is that it can be categorized as A or as B but not any other categories e.g. C or D.

Classifying something into A and B is atypical usage. One could idiomatically classify something into groups, or categories, but not into different values (i.e. A and B) of the group or category.